# Lenovo s10-3 wireless problems

Tags: wireless, xubuntu, lenovo

I have the `Lenovo s10-3` machine and I have wireless problems. I am running xubuntu 12.04. I had to `lspci -k` to identify my driver and install the correct broadcom drivers to get it out of hard blocked. `rfkill` list shows nothing is blocked now and everything seems to be working but it can not find a single wireless connection.

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: May we see those results, please? lspci -nn | grep 0280 and also: rfkill list all

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the "hardware drivers" (which is in the system or settings menu)? Also the command

`sudo dmesg | egrep 'air|ath|carl|at7|iwl|ipw|rtl8|rt2|rt3|rt6|rt7|r818|r871|rtl8|tg3|ssb|wl|b43|bcma|brcm|b44|eth1|ndis|wmi|wlan0'`

can give helpful info.